# stmt->execute do not work when inserting two rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, optimization

Trying to save two rows in table: `victim`

supposing the output was like this:

```
   name  |  age  |  gender |   address            |  Journal_id
----------------------------------------------------------------
  robert |  23   |   M     | st. lucas calabanga  |      1
  vender |  25   |   M     | st. lucas calabanga  |      1
```

I wrote a prepare statement with multiple bind param  here it is:

```
  $j_id = mysqli_insert_id($this->db);

  $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO victim (name, age, gender, address, journal_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

  $length = count($vName);
  for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) 
  {   
       if ($stmt->bind_param('sissi', $vName[$i], $vAge[$i], $vGender[$i], $vAddr[$i], $j_id))

            if($stmt->execute())
                 echo "working";
            else
                 echo "not working";
   }
```

When I run that code it didn't inert in my db. anybody who can who can help me.

Comment: I think u missed this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: "didn't insert" **HOW**? You got "not working"?

Comment: @MarcB  yes, not working...

Comment: Then your query has failed, and you need to check `mysqli_error()` for the reason why.

Comment: I got it, my problem was in the declaration of data type.. I change in already.. thanks alot to all of you..

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {  
    if($stmt->execute(array($vName[$i], $vAge[$i], $vGender[$i], $vAddr[$i], $j_id))) {
        echo "working";
    }
    else {
        echo "not working";
    }
}
```